# "CAS Authentication Wanted!" Laravel 5.5

Tags: authentication, laravel-5, phpcas

I am using subfission/cas "dev-master" branch with Laravel 5.5, PHP 7.0.27 with phpCAS 1.3.5. I have two servers (test and prod) with identical Laravel installations. However, when I go to log in via CAS, one server redirects to the appropriate login screen, while another gives me a white screen with:

> CAS Authentication wanted!
>
> You should already have been redirected to the CAS server. Click here
>   to continue. phpCAS 1.3.5 using server https://example.com/cas/
>   (CAS 2.0)

Clicking on "click here" sends me where I need to go, but I'm very confused as to how this error occurs or even what it means. There doesn't seem to be much documentation on this

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem. Worked fine on local dev, but failed when I went to production. I downgraded to ~2.0.9 and it fixed the issue. (I'm using Laravel 5.4)

Comment: cool. Thanks for providing a working version number. This seems to be the only temporary solution. I noticed I was using the "dev-master" version so that probably has something to do with it as well.